# SQL HierarchyID - Return Descendants and Ancestors that belong to matching query term

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, hierarchy

Thank you for taking the time out to read this post, all help is greatly appreciated.

I need help creating an SQL query that returns all ancestors and descendants of items that match or contain my WHERE query string for the description.

My table is like so:

```
ID         Hierarchy            Name
1            /                  Products  
2            /1/                Cars
3            /1/1/              Red 
4            /1/2/              Blue
5            /2/                Bike
6            /2/1/              Green
7            /2/2/              Red
```

I would like to search by description and all matches should be returned along with their descendants and ancestors.

e.g. Search Term = 'Red'

**Result**

```
ID          Hierarchy           Name
1            /                  Products  
2            /1/                Cars
3            /1/1/              Red 
5            /2/                Bike
7            /2/2/              Red
```

another example:

Search Term = 'bi'

**Result** (because bi is contained in the **Bike** string

```
ID          Hierarchy           Name
1            /                  Products  
5            /2/                Bike
6            /2/1/              Green
7            /2/2/              Red
```

Many thanks,

Rob

**************** EDIT 28-Mar-14 *********************

I'm almost there with the following query. However it only retrieves all ancestors and not descendants.

```
WITH Ancestors(Hierarchy, [Name], AncestorId) AS
(
      SELECT
            Hierarchy, [Name], Hierarchy.GetAncestor(1)
      FROM
            dbo.SpecProducts
      WHERE
            Name = 'Chrome'  -- or whatever you need to select that node

      UNION ALL

      SELECT
            ht.Hierarchy, ht.[Name], ht.Hierarchy.GetAncestor(1)
      FROM
            dbo.SpecProducts ht
      INNER JOIN 
            Ancestors a ON ht.Hierarchy = a.AncestorId
)
SELECT DISTINCT *, Hierarchy.ToString() FROM Ancestors
```

******** *EDIT 07-Mar-14* *********************

@Yousseff DAOUI - In response to your answer, I'm having difficulty converting your code to work with my table. Below is my attempt to make your code work with my Table:

```
DECLARE @p_name NVARCHAR = 'Gr';

WITH Temp AS (SELECT * FROM SpecProducts) -- DB Table

,Temp_parents AS (
    SELECT ID, Hierarchy, Name --, 0 _Level
    FROM
        Temp
    WHERE
            Name LIKE '%'+@p_name+'%'
   UNION ALL
    SELECT tab.ID, tab.Hierarchy, tab.Name --, p._Level+1
    FROM
        Temp tab
    INNER JOIN
        Temp_parents p
            ON p.Hierarchy LIKE tab.Hierarchy+'_/')

,Temp_descendants AS (
    SELECT ID, Hierarchy, Name --, 0 _Level
    FROM
        Temp
    WHERE
            Name LIKE '%'+@p_name+'%'
   UNION ALL
    SELECT tab.ID, tab.Hierarchy, tab.Name --, d._Level-1
    FROM
        Temp tab
    INNER JOIN
        Temp_descendants d
            ON tab.Hierarchy LIKE d.Hierarchy+'_/')


SELECT *
FROM Temp_parents
UNION
SELECT *
FROM Temp_descendants
```

Notice how Line 3 attempts to pull data from my table named SpecProducts:

```
WITH Temp AS (SELECT * FROM SpecProducts) -- DB Table
```

However, MS SQL Server Management Studio keeps outputting the following error when I try to execute the code:

> Msg 403, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
> Invalid operator for data type. Operator equals add, type equals hierarchyid.

Do you know how I can get this to work?

Many thanks.

** 2nd Edit - 07-Mar-14 *******

This seems a bit better, but the query is really slow (I think it's pulling more rows than it should be). Is it because HierarchyID '/' is being returned, thus is then finding all children of the root '/', which is everything?

```
DECLARE @p_name NVARCHAR = 'wallpaper';

WITH Temp AS (SELECT * FROM SpecProducts) -- DB Table

,Temp_parents AS (
    SELECT ID, Hierarchy, Name --, 0 _Level
    FROM
        Temp
    WHERE
            Name LIKE '%'+@p_name+'%'
   UNION ALL
    SELECT tab.ID, tab.Hierarchy, tab.Name --, p._Level+1
    FROM
        Temp tab
    INNER JOIN
        Temp_parents p
            ON p.Hierarchy.ToString() LIKE tab.Hierarchy.ToString()+'_/')

,Temp_descendants AS (
    SELECT ID, Hierarchy, Name --, 0 _Level
    FROM
        Temp
    WHERE
            Name LIKE '%'+@p_name+'%'
   UNION ALL
    SELECT tab.ID, tab.Hierarchy, tab.Name --, d._Level-1
    FROM
        Temp tab
    INNER JOIN
        Temp_descendants d
            ON tab.Hierarchy.ToString() LIKE d.Hierarchy.ToString()+'_/')


SELECT *
FROM Temp_parents
UNION
SELECT *
FROM Temp_descendants
```

******* 3rd EDIT - 07-Mar-14 *****************

Ok, really sorry for the number of edits. But this now seems to work based on Yousseff's code.

```
DECLARE @p_name NVARCHAR(255) = 'natural';

WITH Temp_parents AS (
    SELECT ID, Hierarchy, Name --, 0 _Level
    FROM
        SpecProducts
    WHERE
            Name LIKE '%'+@p_name+'%'
   UNION ALL
    SELECT tab.ID, tab.Hierarchy, tab.Name --, p._Level+1
    FROM
        SpecProducts tab
    INNER JOIN
        Temp_parents p
            ON p.Hierarchy.ToString() LIKE tab.Hierarchy.ToString()+'_/')

,Temp_descendants AS (
    SELECT ID, Hierarchy, Name --, 0 _Level
    FROM
        SpecProducts
    WHERE
            Name LIKE '%'+@p_name+'%'
   UNION ALL
    SELECT tab.ID, tab.Hierarchy, tab.Name --, d._Level-1
    FROM
        SpecProducts tab
    INNER JOIN
        Temp_descendants d
            ON tab.Hierarchy.ToString() LIKE d.Hierarchy.ToString()+'_/')


SELECT *
FROM Temp_parents
UNION
SELECT *
FROM Temp_descendants
```

Comment: did you try my script?

Answer (score 1):

I've got a solution for you, i hope it will help you, Here's the code :

```
DECLARE @p_name NVARCHAR(255) = 'b'


IF OBJECT_ID('Temp') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE Temp

IF OBJECT_ID('Temp_parents') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE Temp_parents

IF OBJECT_ID('Temp_descendants') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE Temp_descendants

SELECT *
INTO Temp
FROM  (
SELECT 1 AS ID, '/' AS Hierarchy, 'Products' Name UNION ALL
SELECT 2 AS ID, '/1/' AS Hierarchy, 'Cars' Name UNION ALL
SELECT 3 AS ID, '/1/1/' AS Hierarchy, 'Red' Name UNION ALL
SELECT 4 AS ID, '/1/2/' AS Hierarchy, 'Blue' Name UNION ALL
SELECT 5 AS ID, '/2/' AS Hierarchy, 'Bike' Name UNION ALL
SELECT 6 AS ID, '/2/1/' AS Hierarchy, 'Green' Name UNION ALL
SELECT 7 AS ID, '/2/2/' AS Hierarchy, 'Red' Name) AS T


DECLARE @v_name_1 NVARCHAR(255)= @p_name;

WITH parents AS (
    SELECT ID, Hierarchy, Name, 0 _Level
    FROM
        Temp
    WHERE
            Name LIKE '%'+@v_name_1+'%'
   UNION ALL
    SELECT tab.ID, tab.Hierarchy, tab.Name, p._Level+1
    FROM
        Temp tab
    INNER JOIN
        parents p
            ON p.Hierarchy LIKE tab.Hierarchy+'_/')



select ID, Hierarchy, Name
INTO Temp_parents
from parents


DECLARE @v_name_2 NVARCHAR(255)= @p_name;

WITH descendants AS (
    SELECT ID, Hierarchy, Name, 0 _Level
    FROM
        Temp
    WHERE
            Name LIKE '%'+@v_name_2+'%'
   UNION ALL
    SELECT tab.ID, tab.Hierarchy, tab.Name, d._Level-1
    FROM
        Temp tab
    INNER JOIN
        descendants d
            ON tab.Hierarchy LIKE d.Hierarchy+'_/')



SELECT ID,Hierarchy ,Name
INTO Temp_descendants
FROM
    descendants
WHERE
        ID IS NOT NULL

SELECT *
FROM Temp_parents
UNION
SELECT *
FROM Temp_descendants


IF OBJECT_ID('Temp') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE Temp

IF OBJECT_ID('Temp_parents') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE Temp_parents

IF OBJECT_ID('Temp_descendants') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE Temp_descendants
```

Good Luck :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's an other way of writing the code based on the first to make the code look easier :)

```
DECLARE @p_name NVARCHAR(255) = 'Gr';

WITH Temp AS (
SELECT 1 AS ID, '/' AS Hierarchy, 'Products' Name UNION ALL
SELECT 2 AS ID, '/1/' AS Hierarchy, 'Cars' Name UNION ALL
SELECT 3 AS ID, '/1/1/' AS Hierarchy, 'Red' Name UNION ALL
SELECT 4 AS ID, '/1/2/' AS Hierarchy, 'Blue' Name UNION ALL
SELECT 5 AS ID, '/2/' AS Hierarchy, 'Bike' Name UNION ALL
SELECT 6 AS ID, '/2/1/' AS Hierarchy, 'Green' Name UNION ALL
SELECT 7 AS ID, '/2/2/' AS Hierarchy, 'Red' Name)
,Temp_parents AS (
    SELECT ID, Hierarchy, Name --, 0 _Level
    FROM
        Temp
    WHERE
            Name LIKE '%'+@p_name+'%'
   UNION ALL
    SELECT tab.ID, tab.Hierarchy, tab.Name --, p._Level+1
    FROM
        Temp tab
    INNER JOIN
        Temp_parents p
            ON p.Hierarchy LIKE tab.Hierarchy+'_/')

,Temp_descendants AS (
    SELECT ID, Hierarchy, Name --, 0 _Level
    FROM
        Temp
    WHERE
            Name LIKE '%'+@p_name+'%'
   UNION ALL
    SELECT tab.ID, tab.Hierarchy, tab.Name --, d._Level-1
    FROM
        Temp tab
    INNER JOIN
        Temp_descendants d
            ON tab.Hierarchy LIKE d.Hierarchy+'_/')


SELECT *
FROM Temp_parents
UNION
SELECT *
FROM Temp_descendants
```

Good Luck

EDIT 07-Mar-14 - For this to work with my table I had to amend it to the following - This now appears work well **

```
DECLARE @p_name NVARCHAR(255) = 'natural';

WITH Temp_parents AS (
    SELECT ID, Hierarchy, Name --, 0 _Level
    FROM
        SpecProducts
    WHERE
            Name LIKE '%'+@p_name+'%'
   UNION ALL
    SELECT tab.ID, tab.Hierarchy, tab.Name --, p._Level+1
    FROM
        SpecProducts tab
    INNER JOIN
        Temp_parents p
            ON p.Hierarchy.ToString() LIKE tab.Hierarchy.ToString()+'_/')

,Temp_descendants AS (
    SELECT ID, Hierarchy, Name --, 0 _Level
    FROM
        SpecProducts
    WHERE
            Name LIKE '%'+@p_name+'%'
   UNION ALL
    SELECT tab.ID, tab.Hierarchy, tab.Name --, d._Level-1
    FROM
        SpecProducts tab
    INNER JOIN
        Temp_descendants d
            ON tab.Hierarchy.ToString() LIKE d.Hierarchy.ToString()+'_/')


SELECT *
FROM Temp_parents
UNION
SELECT *
FROM Temp_descendants
```

Comment: I really appreciate your response. However, I'm having difficulty amending your code to work with my DB table. I tried to respond here but the number of characters is too limited to post my code. See my edit in the main question dated 07-Mar-14. Many thanks.

Comment: Sorry Youssefff, I now seem to have this working. See the edit named 3rd Edit 07-Mar-14. Really appreciate your help.

Comment: Hmm... this doesn't actually appear to work 100%. In some cases not all descendants are bring returned. Generally it seems to be descendants of the found search terms that have further child items. But not always. I can't for the life of me work out why. I've tested it using and adding more rows to your data table "Temp" and it works fine. However it doesn't work properly when using my Database table.

Comment: Sorry Youssef, I had to remove this as the answer. It doesn't work properly in all instances. I can't as of yet work out what the exact cause or method that's causing the problem. Basically, not all matches are being returned in all instances. Also, not all products found based on the query term are pulling all ancestors all of the way up to the root '/'.

Answer (score 0):

maybe like this:

```
select id, HierarchyID, Description from (
select b.id, b.HierarchyID, b.Description, 
case 
when (a.id = b.id) then 1 
when (marker = 1 and num_len > 1 and LEN(replace(b.HierarchyID,'/','')) < num_len and numbers > replace(b.HierarchyID,'/','')) then 1
when (marker = 1 and num_len = 1 and LEN(replace(b.HierarchyID,'/','')) > num_len and numbers < replace(b.HierarchyID,'/','')) then 1
else 0 end as marker from (
select id, SUBSTRING(HierarchyID,2,1) as first_num, 1 as marker, replace(HierarchyID,'/','') as numbers, LEN(replace(HierarchyID,'/','')) as num_len
from my_tab where Description like '%bi%' or HierarchyID = '/') a right join my_tab b on first_num = SUBSTRING(b.HierarchyID,2,1)) c where marker = 1;
```

sorry for my english!

1. select id, the first number you find in HierarchyID ("/2/1/" is 2), a "marker" for the values you found and you want to Keep (marker = 1), the complete number you can find in HierarchyID ("/2/1/" is 21) and the length of the complete number you found in HierarchyID from my_tab table (a) with the search term of your choice.
2. with (1.) we make a right join of the my_tab table (b) to get all the other values.
   first case when: if id from (a)is equal with the id of (b) we take the marker 1 (because thats the values we got with the search term). second case when: if marker is 1 and the length of (a) > 1 (that means we have a value like "/2/1/") and the length of (b) < the length of (a) (that means "/2/2/" has marker = 1 and a length of 2; "/2/1/" has the same length, but we dont want him; we want "/2/") and the complete number you can find in HierarchyID (a) is greater than the complete number you can find in HierarchyID (b) (that means we will get the "/2/" value) we set the marker to 1. third case when: similar to the "second case when". Here we have a look at the values with marker = 1 and a length of 1 ("/2/") to mark all the values like "/2/1/" and "/2/2/" wich we want.
3. now you have all the values you want with a marker = 1.

Comment: Thank you for your input ingwy.
Unfortunately I get the following error:

Msg 8116, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Argument data type hierarchyid is invalid for argument 1 of substring function.
Msg 8156, Level 16, State 1, Line 9
The column 'Hierarchy' was specified multiple times for 'c'.

Comment: i defined varchar for column hierarchyid. everything works fine. wich datatype you are using?

Comment: change the last select to :"select c.id, c.HierarchyID, c.Description from ("

Comment: I'm using the SQL HierarchyID data type for my Hierarchy value

Comment: You wrote it in your title and i didn't really read it. Sorry! If you use a varchar data type and a "normal" column for your HierarchyID column, the script will work ;)

Comment: haha no problem. I had a feel some wires were getting crossed here. Really appreciate you trying to help.